# Synronize bookmarks in Books apps

Tags: macos, ios, books, ipados, bookmarks

I added a PDF and an ePub to my `Books` collection on my Mac; they was synchronized between my iPhone and iPad.

I added bookmarks to the PDF on my iPad and noticed that they were synchronized with my iPhone, but not with my laptop.  I added bookmarks to the ePub file on my iPad and noticed that they were synchronized between all three devices.

`Books` on macOs opens Preview, which may be related to this issue.

Is there to get `Books` on macOs to work the same way with PDFs as the other OS versions?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to edit the PDF that was located in `iCloud Drive/Books`.  Preview is still used, but the synchronization occurs properly.